# Code is working fine, but, not working completely when the whole code is put inside a def() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

**GITHUB REPO:** https://github.com/sunnysinghnitb/color_detector

**THE DIFFERENCE:** The code inside both files is the same. But, the only difference between *color_detection1.py* (70 lines) and *color_detection2.py* (75 lines) is that the whole code inside the second file has been put in the *def colo()* function. Changes in lines 1, 73, 75 of *color_detection2.py*.

**REQUIRED OUTPUT:** Just run the *color_detection1.py* and **double-click** on the output image. This will show the **RGB values** of that particular pixel.

**QUESTION:** The *color_detection1.py* file is running fine and producing the desired output (RGB values) on double-click, while the *color_detection2.py* is not producing the desired output. Why is this happening? Why is *color_detection2.py* not working the same as *color_detection1*.py?

**EDIT:** Suppose the following is some python code (color_detection1.py) which is working fine:

```py
.....
...
..
.....
```

Now, putting this code inside a function (color_detection2.py):

```py
def colo():
    ..... 
    ...
    ..
    .....
    return
colo()
```

The problem is both codes are working differently. The code 1 is working as expected, while, code 2 is working partially. Why is this happening?

Comment: So you're saying there are two files with one difference and they don't behave the same? Maybe the reason is that one difference. But put a [mre] *in the question*.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I just want to know that putting a few lines of code inside a python function can make them work differently?

Comment: Don't put everything into the new function. import statements should stay in the global scope, and you should define your other functions outside of `colo()` and then call them from inside

Comment: So put an example in the question, not just a link and a description.

Comment: Some of us don't have a github. Could you please put all the code instead of "..."?

Comment: It's a basic requirement of SO that you cut your code down  to the minimum that reproduces the issue and include that in the question. It's also basic respect for other people's time, not to mention debugging 101. If you can't be bothered to do that, and would rather just post *dots*, please don't post here in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is one of scope. You set globals here.

```
def draw_function(event, x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        global b,g,r,xpos,ypos, clicked
        clicked = True
        xpos = x
        ypos = y
        b,g,r = img[y,x]
        b = int(b)
        g = int(g)
        r = int(r)
```

That's all well and good but once you place the function definition inside another function you are changing the scope that you need to access it in from `global` to `nonlocal`.

Changing it to this should work.

```
def draw_function(event, x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        nonlocal b,g,r,xpos,ypos, clicked
        clicked = True
        xpos = x
        ypos = y
        b,g,r = img[y,x]
        b = int(b)
        g = int(g)
        r = int(r)
```

Your first step of debugging should be determining how far your program progresses. A little bit of logging can go a long way.

Placing a logger inside of `if (clicked):` would have shown you that `clicked` is never `True` even though you try to set is as such inside your function.

Placing one outside of your `if` statement and inside your function would show you that it is defining it in the function but not outside it.

This lets you narrow down the problem a lot more and you have a reproduceable code snippet you can post.

Comment: Thanks, @Axe319. You just made my day.